# Stop UIPopover from dismissing automatically part II

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uipopovercontroller, uipopover

Sorry I previously posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129243/stop-uipopover-from-dismissing-automatically), but The answers I got didn't work (probably my fault).

Basically, I want to stop a UIPopover from dismissing automatically. I got to this piece of code:

```
    - (BOOL) popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    return NO;
}
```

which I put in, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. Is there anything else I should add?
am I putting it in the right place (I was putting it in the vc.m of the view that has the popover within it)?

Thanks Very Much,

Luke

Answer (score 2):

Check to make sure the `UIPopover` delegate is set. You can do this in code by setting the popover instance variable:

`aPopover.delegate = self;`