# How to prevent a popover from dismissing when clicking outside in Xamarin with C#?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, uipopover

Hello i need to prevent my popover from dismissing when clicking outside the box.

I found some answers but all in objective C and i cant understand it very well.

[Stop UIPopover from dismissing automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129243/stop-uipopover-from-dismissing-automatically)

Anyone knows how to do that in xamarin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIKit's `[UIPopoverControllerDelegate popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:]` translates to [`UIPopoverControllerDelegate.ShouldDismiss` in MonoTouch](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UIPopoverControllerDelegate_Extensions.ShouldDismiss).

```
popover.Delegate = new MyPopoverDelegate();

...

class MyPopoverDelegate : UIPopoverControllerDelegate
{
    public override bool ShouldDismiss (UIPopoverController popoverController)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm not completely positive, but I believe you can also just have your main class implement the `IUIPopoverControllerDelegate` interface and add `ShouldDismiss` directly to it:

```
popover.Delegate = this;

...

public override bool ShouldDismiss (UIPopoverController popoverController)
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Worked and putting ModalInPopover = true; inside the viewDidLoad worked too... Thanks